# Process consuming maximum CPU

Tags: command-line, unix

How do I identify the unix process using the maximum CPU. 
  since i am not a power user.. will i be able to find it using ps command?
  Also, I login to the server using SSH client or telnet..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `top`, by default it lists the most CPU hungry processes at the top. And it has a field for process ID.

Comment: this is easy way to get the info, than the combination of ps & other commands! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
UNIX95= ps -e -o  pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -r | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

htop is top with colours...

Answer (score 0):

Sorted from most demanding to least demanding:
    `ps -arcwwwxo "command %cpu"`

Just the first ten:
`ps -arcwwwxo "command %cpu" | head -13`